# sql 'decode' codes explanation

Tags: sql, oracle, sas

I am a SAS user, and I have a sql code which I don't know the meaning. 
SQL code is as down. Checked 'decode' but what i have is complicated for me. Don't know the meaning.

```
  select           decode( row_number() over (PARTITION BY spriden_id, rjrsear_posn, rjrsear_suff ORDER BY spriden_id, rjrsear_posn, rjrsear_suff, rjrsewh_pay_end_date desc , w_tmi , c_tmi )
                     , 1 , student_name , NULL ) 
  || chr(9) || decode( row_number() over (PARTITION BY spriden_id, rjrsear_posn, rjrsear_suff ORDER BY spriden_id, rjrsear_posn, rjrsear_suff, rjrsewh_pay_end_date desc , w_tmi , c_tmi )
                     , 1 , spriden_id , NULL )
  || chr(9) || decode( row_number() over (PARTITION BY spriden_id, rjrsear_posn, rjrsear_suff ORDER BY spriden_id, rjrsear_posn, rjrsear_suff, rjrsewh_pay_end_date desc , w_tmi , c_tmi )
                     , 1 , trim(rjrsear_posn)||' ('||trim(rjrsear_suff)||')' , NULL )
```

Can you please explain what this code is trying to do? Or is there any way to write with SAS language

Comment: Do you know what `decode` does? And what about the `row_number() over (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY)`?

Comment: What I know is The DECODE function compares expression against each search value in order. That's my question.

Comment: Looks like the `decode` is looking up the result of `row_number` in a list that contains exactly one element, and returning null if the `row_number` return greater than 1. As for why? I have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the DECODE function which is complicated here, but the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY xxx ORDER BY yyy)`.

Per `spriden_id, rjrsear_posn, rjrsear_suff` all records are sorted by `spriden_id, rjrsear_posn, rjrsear_suff, rjrsewh_pay_end_date desc , w_tmi , c_tmi` (well, obviously order by could be reduced to `rjrsewh_pay_end_date desc , w_tmi , c_tmi`). If a result record happens to be the first one per group according to above order (tested with decode and row number 1), then its values are displayed in a tab-separated string otherwise null.

Maybe this is being used as a kind of group title, i.e. rather than showing

```
Tom, 1, A, X, a, b
Tom, 1, A, X, c, d
Tom, 1, A, X, e, f
Joe, 2, A, Y, g, h
Joe, 2, A, Y, i, j
```

you show

```
Tom 1 A (X), a, b
             c, d
             e, f
Joe 2 A (Y), g, h
             i, j
```

(Provided you show the records in the same sort order.)

I see no reason for using three decodes on the same expression here instead of only one, btw.

Comment: If that's what it's doing, then `proc report` would easily handle that in SAS.